# Twisting a line bundle with the zero section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve and $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Denote by $\mathbb{L}$ the line bundle associated to $L$, $\pi:\mathbb{L} \to X$ the natural morphism and $0_\pi$ the zero section to $\pi$. If I understand correctly the morphism $\pi^*:\mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{L})$ is an isomorphism. Then, what is the preimage of the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{L}}(0_\pi)$ on $\mathbb{L}$, under this morphism?

Comment: The inverse isomorphism is $s^*$, where $s:X\to \mathbb{L}$ is the zero section morphism.  Thus, depending on your sign convention (which you have not specified), the pullback $s^*\mathcal{O}(\underline{\text{Image}(s)})$ is either $L$ of the dual of $L$.